# this value is null in function (React-Native)

Tags: listview, this, react-native

As per local testing, 'this' seems to be null inside the row render function. As a result this prevents me from binding a local function on the onPress prop.

I have this render block:

```
render() {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader} 
            style={styles.listView} />
    );
}
```

and a local function

```
_visitEntryDetail() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

then row render

```
_renderRow(something) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            style={[styles.textContainer, filestyle.container]} 
            onPress={this._visitEntryDetail.bind(this)} >
            <View>
                <Text style={filestyle.text1} >{something.detail}</Text>
                <Text style={filestyle.text2} >{something.size}, {something.timestamp}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

This returns

```
message: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.$FileList_visitEntryDetail')"
```

checking "this" on renderRow returns null when replacing code above with:

```
_renderRow(file) {
    console.log(this);
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            style={[styles.textContainer, filestyle.filelistcontainer]} 
             >
```

with following console output:

```
RCTJSLog> null
```

but is fine when

```
render() {
    console.log('inside render. this value is below me');
    console.log(this);
    return (
        <ListView
```

console

```
RCTJSLog> "inside render. this value is below me"
RCTJSLog> [object Object]
```

Can someone please point out what's causing this. Thanks.

Comment: made the code work above by: renderRow={(file) => < TouchableHighlight onPress={this._visitEntryDetail.bind(this)} .... }

Answer (score 47):

`this` is null because `_renderRow` has not been binded to the current class. Please keep in mind:

> In constructor, you need to explicitly bind a function, if you want to pass it to any react component, *as sometimes it doesn't bind implicitly.*

This statement applies to any function being passed to the component. For example, you want to call a function `callThisFunction` on pressing `TouchableHighlight`. You can bind it by:

```js
class SomeComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    //binding function
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)
    this.callThisFunction = this.callThisFunction.bind(this)
  }

  renderRow() {
    console.log(this) //not null now
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.callThisFunction}>
          <Image source={require('image!prev')}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }

  callThisFunction() {
    console.log(this) //not null now
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue - I was getting a slightly different error message: `'null' is not an object (evaluating '_this3.pressRow')`

Comment: Thank you, saved my time. +1

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time! 
Unfortunately, it's not mentioned in the ListView example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: This also solved my problem. I had same issue with @MelihMucuk. So this is exclusive only when using ListView?

Comment: @NightFury that works fine. But when I try pass a parameter to the function I get the error: "undefined is not a function.....". Any suggestions?

Comment: @Larney you could try binding in `componentWillMount` like so -> `this.myFunc = () => this.myFunc(prop1, prop2)`

Comment: It turns out I never binded renderRow inside Listview.  "renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}"

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to NightFury's solution would be to use [ES6 Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax without having to manually bind the function in the constructor. Your `render()` would then look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
       <ListView
           dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
           renderRow={() => this._renderRow()}
           renderHeader={() => this._renderHeader()} 
           style={styles.listView} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass function to a 3rd party component always pass functions like that:

```
        <Carousel
          renderItem={item => this._renderItem(item)}
        />
```

When you bind function like that, it didnt lose function instance in other classes