# React Native undefined in not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to generate a series of button from an array.  I have the following code

```
render: function() {
    var locations = this.state.campus.map(function (item){
        var that = this;
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#dddddd'
                onPress={()=>this.buttonPress("this")}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Campus</Text>
            <View style={styles.flowDown}>
                {locations}
            </View>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#dddddd'
                onPress={()=>this.buttonPress("this")}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>'Hello'</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        </View>
    );
}
```

This renders fine and the button at the bottom works perfectly.  However the buttons generated in the map function product the error when they are pressed.  I have tried the that = this and using bind(this)/bind(that) but I am still getting the error.

Is it possible to generate buttons this way?  I don't want to use ListView since this generates its own whole screen display.

Comment: try explicitly binding the function at the constructor part. see if solution here works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532926/this-value-is-null-in-function-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render: function() {
    var that = this;
    var locations = this.state.campus.map(function (item){
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#dddddd'
                onPress={()=>that.buttonPress("this")}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Campus</Text>
            <View style={styles.flowDown}>
                {locations}
            </View>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#dddddd'
                onPress={()=>this.buttonPress("this")}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>'Hello'</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work.  I also understand why it works which is even better.