# binding a function passed to a component

Tags: react-native

Reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532926/this-value-is-null-in-function-react-native), I understand that when I pass a function to a react component, I have to bind a function in the constructor like this

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //binding function
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.callThisFunction = this.callThisFunction.bind(this);
    }
```

or I'll get an error like this.

> null is not an object: evaluating `this4.functionName`

Following that advice, I bound the function in the constructor but I'm still getting the same error.

I'm making a Master/Detail app with React Native based on the Movies example in the react native repo, except that I don't use this syntax

```
var SearchScreen = React.createClass({
```

(which is what the repo is) but rather this ES6 style syntax

```
class ListOfLists extends Component {
```

In my list view, I render a row like this.

```
  class MovieList extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.selectMovie = this.selectMovie.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
          }),
        };
      }
          renderRow(
            movie: Object,
            sectionID: number | string,
            rowID: number | string,
            highlightRowFunc: (sectionID: ?number | string, rowID: ?number | string) => void,
          ) {
          console.log(movie, "in render row", sectionID, rowID);
            return (
              <ListCell 
                onSelect={() => this.selectMovie(movie)}
                onHighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(sectionID, rowID)}
                onUnhighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(null, null)}
                movie={movie}
              />
            );
          }

       selectMovie(movie: Object) {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          this.props.navigator.push({
            title: movie.name,
            component: TodoListScreen,
            passProps: {movie},
          });
        } else {
          dismissKeyboard();
          this.props.navigator.push({
            title: movie.title,
            name: 'movie',
            movie: movie,
          });
        }
      }
     render(){
        var content = this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0 ?
            <NoMovies  /> :
            <ListView
             ref="listview"
             renderSeparator={this.renderSeparator}
             dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
             renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
             renderRow={this.renderRow} 
             automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
             keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
             keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
             showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
             renderRow={this.renderRow}
     }
```

The key line is `this.selectMovie(movie)`. When I click a row with a movie name, I get an error

> null is not an object: `evaluating this4.selectMovie`

Question: why is it telling me `null is not an object` or rather why is that function null?

Update:

I added the render method to the code to show where `renderRow` is getting used

Comment: I can't see where do you use `renderRow` but you might need to bind it too. However you don't need to combine arrow functions and binding.

Comment: @sodik I updated the OP to show where `renderRow` is used

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Way to deal with this problem without modifying your code a lot is adding 
`this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)` to your class constructor.

```
class New extends Component{   
  constructor(){
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)
  }

  render(){...} 
}
```

you have add the property `renderRow = { this.renderRow }`,In fact the renderRow executed with [binded to null object](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0aea74ebeac2600d70a8dd1bd8dd20a3c563a718/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js#L407-L412).Try to console `this` in `renderRow` you will find it is `GlobalObject` instead of `Class MovieList` which you desire to.

Comment: I might be confused, but is this really the proper solution to this problem? The answer does not explain what is causing the issue in the first place, and it seems like a hack.

Comment: @PixelCakeGames Thanks for figuring out that the answer hasn't been given at the beginning,while I don't this this is a 'hack' instead of solution.It's clear that renderRow method be executed width binding to a` null` object ,and that's what @Leahcim crash into.

Answer (score 1):

Try using es6 syntax :

```
selectMovie = (movie) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: movie.name,
      component: TodoListScreen,
      passProps: {movie},
    });
  } else {
    dismissKeyboard();
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: movie.title,
      name: 'movie',
      movie: movie,
    });
  }
}
```

and then

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.selectMovie = this.selectMovie();
  this.state = {
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    })
  };
}
```

and

```
renderRow = (...) => {
  return (
    <ListCell 
      onSelect={this.selectMovie(movie)}
      onHighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(sectionID, rowID)}
      onUnhighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(null, null)}
      movie={movie}
    />
  );
}
```