# this.props undefined in class method

Tags: react-native

I have a component with `render` and `onPress` methods described below...

```
  onCardPressed(event) {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { data } = this.props;
    console.log(event, data);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.onCardPressed}
      >
        <Container style={{ elevation: 5 }}>
          <SectionTitle>
            This is a
            {` ${data.city} `}
            card
          </SectionTitle>
        </Container>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

In this example, the card will properly display `This is a London card`, but in the onPress method `this.props` returns `undefined`.

How can I access the `this.props` object for evaluation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this value is null in function (React-Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532926/this-value-is-null-in-function-react-native)

Comment: This is a problem of correctly binding the function to the scope. Below answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by two way. The argument in favour of adding these lines to the constructor is so that the new bound functions are only created once per instance of the class. You could also use

```
onPress={this.onCardPressed.bind(this)}
```

or (ES6):

```
onPress={() => this.onCardPressed()}
```